# Transform operation in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `matrix` in `matlab` which look like:

```
A= 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6
```

I want to convert into the following matrix:

```
1 0 0 0
5 2 0 0
3 6 3 0
0 4 7 4
0 0 5 8
0 0 0 6
```

How can I do this transformation?

Comment: You can start by designing the logic...

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `-1:` What have you tried ?

Comment: No I am trying but not getting the exact answer. Could you help me to design the logic?

Comment: so you want reverse-engineering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you have the matrix in MATLAB, I assume you want a solution in MATLAB. You can use the `diag` function to write each row to the corresponding diagonal.

```
% Create A and get size
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 3 4 5 6];
[m n] = size(A);

% Preallocate square matrix with correct number of rows
B = zeros(n + m-1);

% Put each row of A in the corresponding diagonal
for k=1:m
    B(1:n-(1-k),1:n-(1-k)) = B(1:n-(1-k),1:n-(1-k))  + diag(A(k,:),1-k);
end

% Crop B to get correct size
B = B(:,1:n);
```